# How to write a Javascript function that sorts account numbers in a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

Write a function that sorts account numbers in a string and returns a string of sorted account numbers. Also remove the duplicates and add the number of duplicates at the end of the original bankNumber
ex:

```
12455 1435 5
 12455 1435 5
```

will be:

```
12455 1435 52
```

example:

```
 var input = `2
 5
 12455 1435 5
 12455 1435 5
 23454 3554 5 
 12344 1435 30
 12344 1435 30

 2
 41234 5451 9 
 13451 5151 5
 `;

output = "2
 5
 12344 1435 302
 12455 1435 52
 23454 3554 5 

 2
 13451 5151 5
 41234 5451 9 
 "
```

I have split the strings in to a array using split("\n").
    and sorted the array using a for loop and sort().
    Mostly having trouble getting it sort both transactions.

Thanks.

This is what i have so far:

```
function sort(a) {
  let totalTests = a.slice(0, 1);
  let newString = a.slice(2);
  let arr = newString.split("\n");
  let tempBankNumbers = 0;

  let multiArr = [];
  let arr2 = [1]
  let tempBankNumberAmount = arr2.splice(0, 1);
  let totalTestsInt = parseInt(totalTests);

    for(let i = 0; i < totalTestsInt -1 ; i++)
  {
    let arrayTemp = arr.splice(0, arr.indexOf(""))
   multiArr[i] = (arrayTemp)
  }
  arr2.sort();

  var tempBankNumber = "";

  let returnArray = [];
  returnArray.push(tempBankNumberAmount[0]);

  for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    tempBankNumber = arr2[i];
    let numberOfAccounts = 1;

    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr2.length; j++) {
      if (arr2[i] == (arr2[j])) {

        arr2[i] = arr2[i].concat(++numberOfAccounts)
        arr2.splice(j, 1)
      }
    }
  }
  arr2.unshift(tempBankNumberAmount[0])
  return a; 
}
```

Comment: this is what i have so far

Comment: there's no need to split them, lexical sorting works fine

Comment: i also need to delete the duplicates and cancat the number of duplicates at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put comments into how it works.  I'm assuming they should be lexical sorted only based on original values, and not based on appended string.
Uses object map to keep track of dupe count, then unwraps object map.

```js
var input = `2
 5
 12455 1435 5
 12455 1435 5
 23454 3554 5 
 12344 1435 30
 12344 1435 30

 2
 41234 5451 9 
 13451 5151 5
 `;

const [t, ...split] = input.split(/\s*\n+\s*/)

const r = [], rn = []
let n
while (n = split.shift()) {
  rn.push(n)
  r.push(
    Object.entries(
      // sort first
      split.splice(0, +n).sort()
        // increment object map count value
        .reduce((a, x) => (a[x] = (a[x] || 0) + 1, a), {}))
     // append count if > 1
    .map(([k, v]) => `${k}${v>1?v:''}`))
}

// concat the input count numbers in the input and join result array
console.log(t+'\n'+r.map((x,i)=>`${rn[i]}\n${x.join('\n')}`).join('\n'))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks now i will try to unpack this. I did java script a while ago. so coming back after a couple of years.

Comment: could you explain:.reduce((a, x) => (a[x] = (a[x] || 0) + 1, a), {}))? im not sure what the , a is for or the , {}

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator `(a,b,c,d,e,f)===f`.  I probably wouldn't use it in real production code shared with others, unless I had a very good reason to or the code is very significantly cleaner for it, but it's shorter while allowing me to use array assignment instead of using spread operators to merge.  So as to return the full object for the next iteration of reduce

Comment: The `{}` is to initialize the object map.  Otherwise reduce uses the first object in the array, which is not what I want.